# How do I get a user's profile path in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

How do I get a user's profile path in Drupal based on the author of the current node?

```
<?php print t('Posted on !date by !username', array('!username' => theme('username', $node), '!date' => format_date($node->created,'custom','m.d.y'))); ?>
```

The above gets me the right url, but that's all i want... the url.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$link = drupal_get_path_alias('user/' . $node->uid);`

At least I think that's the most direct. I'm sure there's a more correct answer though.

Comment: Also, I think in your theme templates $author is available directly.

Comment: i wasn't able to get the author var but, get_path_alias was exactly what i was looking for thank you!

Comment: If you're using this to link to the user page (the common use case), you can skip drupal_get_path_alias and just pass the user/# path to l (http://api.drupal.org/api/function/l/6), which will convert it to the alias for you.

Comment: And if you don't need the full link with l(), just url() will get it for you as well. $link = url('user/22323');